# Keep bash script while loop conditional from printing to console

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The following successfully prevents my cacti backup script from running while data is being updated, but I would prefer it if the conditional "ps -C php -f  | grep poller" wasn't continuously printing to the console. How can I accomplish this?

```
#wait till cron job done running:
while  ps -C php -f  | grep poller
do
sleep 1
done
echo "Cron job done. Starting backup"
```

Comment: This does not "print to console".  It prints to stdout.  Do not conflate the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `-q` option to `grep` so it doesn't print the output

```
while ps -C php -f | grep -q poller
```

Comment: That did it. The print stream stopped but it still passed data to the "while" function.